# Bulk Updating to "/_layouts/15/"

Tags: 2013, url, alternate-access-mapping, redirect, hive

I have a farm solution in which the links only seem to work if I update

```
"/_layouts/<xxxx>"
```

with

```
"_layouts/15/<xxxx>"
```

I'd like to do a bulk find, replace but wanted to ask if this is the best practice, and if not, should it be done at the URL level?

Comment: is it in code or only in declarative files?

Answer (score 1):

_layouts was for 2010. So it's perfectly fine to replace it with _layouts/15 because of a new virtual folder called 15 in the layouts folder in 2013. Some googling got me this : http://yalla.itgroove.net/2013/02/07/sharepoint-2013-_layouts15-vs-_layouts-folder-differences/

Comment: Absolutely. So it's all good to change them. I guess I was looking for an easy way out instead of changing hundreds of references :P